# Clicking on a link in Selenium Webdriver doesn't properly dismiss the popup the link is attached to

Tags: java, macos, firefox, selenium, junit

I am struggling to click a link which appears on a modal dialog via java in selenium.  I have the following modal dialog that appears on a web page:

```
<div modal="" class="modal ng-scope visible" ng-init="mController='createPromptController'; mTemplate='states/global/modals/create-prompt/create-prompt.html'; mText='SELECT ONE';"><div class="modal-table">
    <div class="modal-table-cell">
        <div scope-element="innerModal" style="position:relative;">
            <div class="modal-button-close-line">
                <div ng-click="obj.close()" class="modal-button-close">
                  <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div ng-controller="createPromptController" class="ng-scope"><div close-me-blur="blurObj" class="ng-isolate-scope">
            <div class="header">
                <h3 class="title ng-binding">SELECT ONE</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="content text-center">
                <p>Which create mode would you like to use?</p>
                <a class="tiny button medium-text" href="" ng-click="select('wizard')"><i class="fa fa-magic"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Wizard</a>
                <a id="ExperiencesCreateModeAdvanced" class="tiny button medium-text" href="" ng-click="select('advanced')"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Advanced</a>
                <label>remember my selection&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="rememberCreateChoice" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
                </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have been trying to click the Advanced button but the commands I have tried never seem to work:

```
    //This call causes the Advanced button to be highlighted and the underlying page to change but the modal dialog does not actually go away.
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.modal-table.div.modal-table-cell.div.div.ng-scope.div.ng-isolate-scope.div.content.text-center.a#ExpAdvance.tiny.button.medium-text.i.fa.fa-cogs")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);

    //These calls generat an "Unable to locate element" error
    //as does any case variation of the word advanced
    //even using select(advanced) or select('advanced') fails 
    //with or without adding additional slashes to escape the quotes.
    driver.findElement(By.name("Advanced")).click();   
    driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("advanced"));           
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Advanced")).click();  

    //This call highlights the icon for the button but doesn't actually click   
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("i.fa.fa-cogs")).click();  

    //These calls don't error out but also don't click either
    driver.findElement(By.id("ExperiencesCreateModeAdvanced")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/i")).click();
```

I have even looked at clicking on a set of coordinates but I haven't figured out the proper way to do it.  What's weird is that some of the click commands work fine in selenium ide such as clicking this advanced button but then nothing works when I try to do it programmatically.

As far as I can tell, the code isn't inside of an iframe.

I have also tried adding different delays in case it is a timing issue such as by doing:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

It doesn't seem to make a difference in this case.  I have tried using both .click() and .sendKeys(Keys.RETURN) but neither actually makes a difference.  I have dug through a lot of articles both on stackoverflow and on google in general but I haven't made any progress.  This site seems to use a lot of these modal dialogs so its vital I get this figured out.  Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to active window before clicking on any element from the page

```
driver.switchTo().activeElement();
```

Comment: That didn't help either.  The Advanced button never gets clicked regardless of whether I call the line above or not.

Answer (score 0):

It fails to find the web element because the text you provided doesn't match the case sensitivity or the leading space.

So to find these elements by link text :

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("  Advanced")) 
driver.findElement(By.linkText("  Wizard"))
```

Or by partial link text :

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Advanced"))
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Wizard"))
```

Comment: Neither of the suggestions worked.  The most that happens is the Advanced button is highlighted but never clicked.

Comment: So now you are able to locate them?

Comment: sorry for the confusion.  I have always been able to locate them so I have redefined my question to more adequately explain what I am trying to do which is dismiss the dialog by clicking on it.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't ideal but its the closest I have been able to get to making this work.  I am posting this in case anyone comes across this in the future.  Clicking the Advanced button using selenium causes the underlying function to be called but does not make the UI change.  So I end up canceling the Advanced/Wizard dialog by clicking the X button to close the popup after the Advanced page has loaded underneath.

```
    //Click Advanced
    //This is an ugly hack to click the advanced button but its the only way I can get selenium to work
    //Highlight advanced (which loads the create new experience page behind modal dialog, wait 5 seconds,
    //highlight the close button, wait 5 seconds, close modal dialog
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("i.fa.fa-cogs")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/i")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("  Advanced")).click();
```